# Is it possible to set up Chrome Remote Desktop from the command line?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, remote-desktop

Chrome Remote Desktop is a lot better on linux than any kind of VNC type set up.

I'd like to run a linux desktop in the cloud, and use Chrome Remote Desktop to access it.

Can I set this up, without having to set up VNC first?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to set it up using the linux command line by following this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/795703/chrome-remote-desktop-access-to-headless-ubuntu-server-16-04-machine

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.